# Is it possible to add a dropdown to an hta application that only loads the selected data from the source?

Tags: html, hta

I have an HTA application that uses a text file as a data source. The text file has a list of vendors and invoices that gets updated every day. The problem is that the HTA loads all the data as soon as it's opened and it takes some time to complete. Is there a way to only load data that fits criteria from the drop-downs such as selecting the vendor ID or invoice amount or both? Here is the code for my application.

```
 <title>Accounts Payable Invoices</title>
    <head>
    <HTA:Application
         APPLICATIONNAME="AP INVOICES"
         Scroll="yes"
    >


    </head>

    <HTML>
    <BODY>

    <OBJECT id="serviceList" CLASSID="clsid:333C7BC4-460F-11D0-BC04-0080C7055A83">
     <PARAM NAME="DataURL" VALUE="C:\Users\Public\AP_Invoice.prn">
     <PARAM NAME="UseHeader" VALUE="TRUE">
     <PARAM NAME="TextQualifier" VALUE="&quot;">
     <PARAM NAME="SortColumn" VALUE="Vendor;GL Date">

    </OBJECT>
    <H2>Accounts Payable Invoices</H2>
    <table border='1' width='100%' cellspacing='0' datasrc=#serviceList>
    <THEAD><TR>
    <TD><b>Vendor</TD>
    <TD><b>Invoice</TD>
    <TD><b>GL Date</TD>
    <TD><b>Invoice Amount</TD>
    <TBODY>
    <TR>
    <TD><DIV datafld="Vendor"></DIV></TD>
    <TD><DIV datafld="Invoice"></DIV></TD>
    <TD><DIV datafld="GL Date"></DIV></TD>
    <TD><DIV datafld="Invoice Amount"></DIV></TD>
    </TR>
    </THEAD>
    </TR>
    </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Comment: You could read the data line by line and accept only some lines, but that probably would be slower than reading the entire file at once.

Answer (score 1):

The [Tabular Data Control](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dhejo_vanissery/2007/09/06/using-tabular-data-control-to-display-csv-files/) you're using has a [DATAPAGESIZE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/jj160679(v%3Dvs.85)) property that limits the number of pages rendered. Rendering a table in HTML is slow when there are a lot of records, because they all have to be loaded before the table can be rendered.

Try it and see if your table performs any better.

```
   <table border='1' width='100%' cellspacing='0' datasrc=#serviceList DATAPAGESIZE=2>
```

Also, you have improper nesting of the closing THEAD tag. Move these two tags above the `<TBODY>` tag:

```
</THEAD>
</TR>
```